# Solspace tag entries pagination links

Tags: stash, solspace, switchee, solspace-tag

I'm using tag entries like in Docs

```
{exp:tag:entries
        inclusive="yes"
        orderby="entry_date"
        sort="asc"
        limit="10"
        paginate="bottom"        
        websafe_separator="+" 
    }
{tag_paginate}
        <div class="large-12 medium-12 columns center navigation-footer default_font">                            
            {tag_pagination_links}                            
        </div>
    {/tag_paginate}
```

But pagination links are generated without visual separator between words (its empty space, no +), the pagination actually works, but I have different links..

Am I missing some extra parameter to get pagination working. I'm using Stash partials and the tag_pagination is inside Switch case.

thanks

Comment: Can you try the above code on a *completely, absolutely blank EE template with nothing whatsoever on it besides the code*? This will eliminate a lot of possible causes for your issue. Can you also give examples of your current URL, and the pagination URLs created? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I opened test template under main template group called 'test' and I pasted very simple tags
{exp:tag:entries  
    orderby="entry_date"
    sort="asc"
    limit="10"
    paginate="bottom"        
    websafe_separator="+" 
}

{title}<br/>
{tag_paginate}                           
    {tag_pagination_links}                            
{/tag_paginate}
{/exp:tag:entries}

I get my list when I call this url
http://domain.com/home/test/tag/art+lovers
First page is open as this http://domain.com/home/test/tag/art%20lovers/P10

and so on.. everything is working, only the separator is empty space