# Solspace Tag: Pagination generates %20-links, despite correct websafe-setting

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

when I use the pagination inside the exp:tag:entries-loop the links generated look like

```
xy.com/blog/tag/Tipps%20für%20Lehrer/P10
```

instead of

```
xy.com/blog/tag/Tipps+für+Lehrer/P10
```

It's exactly the same problem which is asked [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20801/solspace-tag-entries-pagination-links) (but not solved), except I am not using stash. Thread-starter Davor Peic tried with a spartanic clean template and had the same problem.

Therefore I do not molest you with my code but just want to ask if you could verify that this is a bug or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also issue with EE pagination, which Tag uses: if you use the same URL, eg `http://example.com/entries/two+apples` with pagination in `{exp:channel:entries}`, the pagination URL can become `http://example.com/entries/two apples`. Spaces in URLs render as `%20` in the address bar, which is the URL entity equivalent of a space.

There is possibly a way to prevent `+` to convert to a space by making trial-and-error changes in .htaccess, but another method could be to enable PHP in your templates and put a search & replace function to convert spaces to `+` in pagination urls:

```
<?php echo str_replace(' ', '+', '{pagination_url}'); ?>
```

I posted this answer in the wrong thread earlier, but answering your follow-up question, you can use PHP, but plugins (of the search & replace type) *might* be able to do the same. Unfortunately this issue is because if the EE pagination library, and how it handles the generation of pagination code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; so that means that in every case you use the default websafe-separator "+" you have to use php to generate correct URLs in the pagination?

Comment: You can use PHP, but plugins (of the search & replace type) _might_ be able to do the same.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! I would have wished that I don't need to use PHP for a feature that is very basic and fundamental; perhaps you could integrate the solution in a further update of Tag.