# pagniation_page_number-variable does not parse in Solspace Tag-Module

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

I am using this code inside the exp:tag:entries-loop to generate pagination:

```
{tag_paginate}
                {tag_pagination_links}
                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 text-center"><!-- col-md-offset-3 -->
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        {first_page}
                            <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">Erste Seite</a></li>
                        {/first_page}

                        {previous_page}
                            <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Vorige Seite</a></li>
                        {/previous_page}

                        {page}
                            <li {if current_page}class="active"{/if}><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
                        {page}

                        {next_page}
                            <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Nächste Seite</a></li>
                        {/next_page}
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /col-md-offset-3 -->
                {/tag_pagination_links}
                {/tag_paginate}
```

The variable pagniation_page_number is not parsed, the same for the variable page - see screenshot attached:
[image: Screenshot of broken pagination links]

Could you please give me a hint how this could be fixed?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of Tag and EE are you using? Please provide exact version numbers. This worked on our side: if it isn't on yours, can you provide your full template code? Is your `{exp:tag:entries}` code wrapped in another tag?

Comment: EE v2.8.1 - Build Date: 20140314, Tag 4.2.8 - The exp:tag:entries-tag is not wrapped inside another tag, it's a separate embed-template. I have sent it to you via Solspace Helpdesk-ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - the problem was trivial. As you can see in the template-code above I just missed a slash. This one

```
{page}
   {pagination_url}{pagination_page_number}
{page}
```

just has to be replaced with

```
{page}
   {pagination_url}{pagination_page_number}
{/page}
```

It was worked out by the excellent and engaged guy from Solspace - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is also issue with EE pagination, which Tag uses: if you use the same URL, eg `http://example.com/entries/two+apples` with pagination in `{exp:channel:entries}`, the pagination URL can become `http://example.com/entries/two apples`. Spaces in URLs render as `%20` in the address bar, which is the URL entity equivalent of a space.

There is possibly a way to prevent `+` to convert to a space by making trial-and-error changes in .htaccess, but another method could be to enable PHP in your templates and put a search & replace function to convert spaces to `+` in pagination urls:

```
<?php echo str_replace(' ', '+', '{pagination_url}'); ?>
```

Comment: Sorry! Answered in the wrong thread. The answer should go here (which I have posted and answered to your follow-up question): http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30838/solspace-tag-pagination-generates-20-links-despite-correct-websafe-setting/30865#30865